# dynamic javascript/php form with radios creating a second field

Tags: javascript, forms, textbox, radio-button, dynamic-forms

I'm having a little 'teething' problem here is my code so far

```
<form name="job_app">
    Source?<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="source" value="GAZ" id="GAZ" /> Stonoway Gazette <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="source" value="JCP" id="JCP" /> Job Center <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="source" value="WOM" id="WOM" /> Word of Mouth <br/><br/>

    <script language="text/JavaScript">
        if (document.job_app.source.GAZ.checked){
            document.write='Issue <br/><input type="text" name="issue" /><br/><br/>';
        }
        else if (document.job_app.source.JCP.checked){
            document.write='Ref <br/><input type="text" name="ref" /><br/><br/>';
        }
        //word of mouth has no additional input so there is no if statement for it
    </script>
</form>
```

what i want this to do is create (or unhide) the issue or ref text box depending on which radio button is selected without creating multiple text boxes.

sorry for any inconvenience if this is a rookie mistake, i have never worked with java before nor a language like it.

This is the working code as of 07:15 26/05/2012 as thanks to Amy McCrobie.
It has undergone some edits since Amy's version (see below) i have moved all scripts above the form to make adding the next few fields easier, added a statement for word of mouth, omitted `<head>` as that is part of index.php and meta.php while this is for form.php, added a spacer and made the function name more specific.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <?php
            include './meta.php';
        ?>
    </head>
    <?php
        /*if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            include './submit.php';
        }
        else{*/
            include './form.php';
        //}
    ?>
</html>
```

meta.php

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
<meta http-Equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache" />
<meta http-Equiv="Pragma" Content="no-cache" />
<meta http-Equiv="Expires" Content="0" />
<title>job_app</title>
<link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css"/>
```

form.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#issueEl").hide();
    $("#refEl").hide();
});
    function showHide_source(){
        if (document.getElementById('GAZ').checked)
        {
            document.getElementById('issueEl').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('refEl').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('src_spEl').style.display = 'none';
        } 
        if (document.getElementById('JCP').checked)
        {
            document.getElementById('issueEl').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('refEl').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('src_spEl').style.display = 'none';
        }
    if (document.getElementById('WOM').checked)
        {
            document.getElementById('issueEl').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('refEl').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('src_spEl').style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
</script>
<form name="job_app" action="" method="post"> 
    Source?<br/> 
        <input type="radio" name="source" value="GAZ" id="GAZ" onChange="showHide_source()" /> Stonoway Gazette <br/> 
        <input type="radio" name="source" value="JCP" id="JCP" onChange="showHide_source()" /> Job Center <br/> 
        <input type="radio" name="source" value="WOM" id="WOM" onChange="showHide_source()" /> Word of Mouth <br/><br/> 
    <div class="hideable" id="issueEl">Issue <br/><input type="text" name="issue" /><br/><br/></div>
    <div class="hideable" id="refEl">Ref <br/><input type="text" name="ref" /><br/><br/></div>
    <div class="hideable" id="src_spEl"></div>
    rest of form        
    <input...
     .../>
</form>
```

style.css

```
div.hideable{
    height: 62px;
}
```

Comment: if there is a way to do the 'if checked' bit in php please tell me as i can work with that

Comment: make sure to see my latest edit :-)

Comment: the last edit to my answer is working on [my test site](http://eintranet.r717.net/test/test.php). Hope this has been helpful to you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
    <meta http-Equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache">
    <meta http-Equiv="Pragma" Content="no-cache">
    <meta http-Equiv="Expires" Content="0">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#issueEl").hide();
            $("#refEl").hide();
        });
    </script>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="job_app" action="" method="post"> 
    Source?<br/> 
        <input type="radio" name="source" value="GAZ" id="GAZ" onChange="showHide()" /> Stonoway Gazette <br/> 
        <input type="radio" name="source" value="JCP" id="JCP" onChange="showHide()" /> Job Center <br/> 
        <input type="radio" name="source" value="WOM" id="WOM" onChange="showHide()" /> Word of Mouth <br/><br/> 
        <div id="issueEl">Issue <br/><input type="text" name="issue" /><br/><br/></div>
        <div id="refEl">Issue <br/><input type="text" name="ref" /><br/><br/></div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showHide(){
    if (document.getElementById('GAZ').checked)
    {
        document.getElementById('issueEl').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('refEl').style.display = 'none';
    } 
    if (document.getElementById('JCP').checked)
    {
        document.getElementById('issueEl').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('refEl').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the div boxes don't appear when i select the related radio button

Comment: i copped and pasted your code for accuracy ill try the j query version you have just generated

Comment: is id supposed to be declared twice in the j query version?

Comment: Nope. It is not declared twice. Also, I fixed the javaScript version for you ;-) Maybe the jQuery version makes more sense now - removed the id attributes from the text inputs.

Comment: sorry i should have quoted but look here `<input **id="GAZ"** type="radio" name="source" value="GAZ" **id="GAZ"** />`

Comment: ive uploaded the code so far so you can see what's happening i am using the j query version [link](http://hhaddow.co.uk/job_app/)

Comment: i corrected the 'onload' no change and the jQuery produces the same effect is it working for you [link](http://hhaddow.co.uk/job_app/) as i am beginning to think this is a client side problem

Comment: still not working i have tried putting the script above/outside the body

Comment: okay - I just worked on it on [my site](http://eintranet.r717.net/test/test.php) Check it out - it works fine now ;) So, I copied the other guy's comment and changed it to make it easy on myself, however, his code had many problems. For one, `<script language="text/JavaScript">` should be `<script type="text/javascript">`. He had the id listed twice on your radio inputs, and the code definitely needed to be in a function.

Comment: works only i have had to add 
`if (document.getElementById('WOM').checked){`
`document.getElementById('issueEl').style.display = 'none';`
`document.getElementById('refEl').style.display = 'none';}`
to make the text box disappear if word of mouth is selected after one of the other two

Comment: the `<script language="text/JavaScript">` is my fault well the fault f some blogger i copied and pasted some of my original code form

Comment: i just want to say you have been a tremendous help and my understanding of java has increased tenfold

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest jQuery, it's not hard to learn, in fact I find it much easier than basic javascript
also I would go the route of two textboxes that are hidden, and then showing them via jQuery

as it stands now I think if the user checks one radio button and then the other two text boxes will appear

and with jQuery added (which is as easy as including the sript at the top of your page your code would be more like this...

```
<form name="job_app"> 
    Source?<br/> 
        <input id="GAZ" type="radio" name="source" value="GAZ" id="GAZ" /> Stonoway Gazette <br/> 
        <input id="JCP" type="radio" name="source" value="JCP" id="JCP" /> Job Center <br/> 
        <input id="WOM" type="radio" name="source" value="WOM" id="WOM" /> Word of Mouth <br/><br/> 
        Issue <br/><input id="issue" type="text" name="issue" /><br/><br/>
        Issue <br/><input id="ref" type="text" name="ref" /><br/><br/>

    <script language="text/JavaScript">

        $("#issue").css("display","none"); 
        $("#ref").css("display","none"); 

        if ($("#GAZ").checked){ 
            $("#issue").css("display","inline"); 
            $("#ref").css("display","none"); 

        } 
         if ($("#JCP").checked){ 
            $("#issue").css("display","none"); 
            $("#ref").css("display","inline"); 

        } 
        //word of mouth has no additional input so there is no if statement for it 
    </script> 
</form>
```

Comment: if you want to use jQuery, you should use `show()` and `hide()`... `$("#issue").show();` and `$("#issue").hide();`... just a suggestion :-)

Comment: I have had issues with `show()` and `hide()` working the same way accross browsers and behaving differently with different elements, I like editting the css, I do use `toggle/slideToggle` (which esentially shows and hides, when I want something to fade or slide or whatever but) display none/inline/block etc.. has worked better for me